# How to convert mixed values to integer in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, types

I have a column in DataFrame as:

```
column1
Jone
Jeck
42
Fin
Tom
45
```

All values are str. How can I convert 42 and 45 to int type?

Comment: val = '42' ; int(val)?

Answer (score 2):

Use custom function, but practically working with mixed data later is really pain:

```
def f(x):
    try:
        return int(x)
    except:
        return x

df['column1'] = df['column1'].apply(f)
print (df)
  column1
0    Jone
1    Jeck
2      42
3     Fin
4     Tom
5      45

print (df['column1'].apply(type))
0    <class 'str'>
1    <class 'str'>
2    <class 'int'>
3    <class 'str'>
4    <class 'str'>
5    <class 'int'>
Name: column1, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#Use isdigit function where ever you are using the column names
#Example

a = "12"
b = "stackoverflow"
if(a.isdigit):  #returns true and will change it to integer
    a = int(a)
if(b.isdigit):   #returns false thus it will not be exectuted
    b = int(b)
```